# jQuery .text() not working with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string

With the piece of code below:

```
if (params.showTooltip) {
      map.label.text(mapData.pathes[code].name);
      jQuery(params.container).trigger(labelShowEvent, [map.label, code]);

      if (!labelShowEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        map.label.show();
        map.labelWidth = map.label.width();
        map.labelHeight = map.label.height();
      }
}
```

I'm getting things like in the displayed label:

```
<strong>X Name</strong><br>Second line<br>Third line
```

What I need is to get this in the displayed label:

**X Name**
Second Line
Third Line

I guess I need to convert parse map.label.txt as html but I don´t know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you're actually asking, but try using `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

`.text()` just adds whatever string you provide as plain text inside your HTML element, whereas `.html()` actually renders any HTML elements within that string.

Comment: Can´t believe. As simple as this. Many thanks joshfarrant.

Comment: No problem, mark as correct if you're happy with it, but just try and make the actually question part of your question a bit more obvious in future :)